# publish local files to deployer without creating component

Tags: 2013, publishing

I have created one multimedia component having extension zip.when we are publishing multimedia component I want extract and publish it into deployer with same folder structure.
For example we are having a.zip file when we are extraction it will extract 
 - HTML 
 - Images
 - Css
 - Js
 - Media
 - PDF
 - Fonts
above folders have files.
I have created C# TBB and this code have logic for

- extracting zip file into local folder
- read one by one folder,create structure group for that folder and publish all files in that folder.

Binary binary = engine.PublishingContext.RenderedItem.AddBinary(ms, "filename", rootStructureGroup, rootStructureGroup.Id, maincomponent, "image/png");

But in deployer it is publishing one file in every folder.
Could you please help me in placing all the files in folder.

Answer (score 1):

For this scenario, I guess you need to write a Storage Extension *(or may be Deployer Extension or Custom Resolver as there may be difference of opinion)*.

In Storage Extension (or Deployer Extension), you will get an extension point during the Publishing process in which you can write your custom code (in JAVA) to perform the extraction of items of Zip file and deploy them as per your business logic.

You may refer [THIS](http://pankajgaur83.wordpress.com/2014/07/18/tridion-2013-storage-extension-for-dynamic-component-presentations/) post to get your hands on the Storage Extension.

You may refer [THIS](http://www.tridiondeveloper.com/the-story-of-sdl-tridion-2011-custom-resolver-and-the-allowwriteoperationsintemplates-attribute) post for Custom Resolver

You may refer [THIS](https://sdltridionworld.com/articles/sdltridion2011/tutorials/Deployer_Extensions_With_Eclipse_1.aspx) post for Deployer Extension